# float left div disappears when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a very simple structure, it's basically just 2 divs (1/3 + 2/3), but the right div disappears when i resize che window, even if i set a min-width.

PS: I'd need it to stop being responsive when it reaches a 1280px resolution.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

```
#contents {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 54px auto 0px auto;
    }

        #content-1 {
            min-width: 426px;
            width: 33%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            border-right: 1px solid black;

        }

        #content-2 {
                min-width: 852px;
                width: 66%;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
                background-color: #FF6164;
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't disappear. But the `min-width` will mess with the responsiveness and part of those elements will be out of the window depending on the window width. Here it is without the `min-width`, seems fine to me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VppRgq

Comment: I'd need it to stop being responsive when it reaches a 1280px resolution tho, because of a pretty complex organization of the text.

Comment: If you need elements to behave differently depending on screen size, then you want to use Media Queries. (If those are a complete unknown to you so far - which is what your comment reads like - then please go read up on them; they are _the_ most basic technique you need to know about when it comes to responsiveness.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `min-width` since your divs will not be able to maintain that minimum width and still be responsive. When they try to do so, the right div is thrown to the bottom.